# ForeignKey is always OFF and not working between tables in SQLalchemy in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

my code for db in Flask and SQLalchemy is working but when I make comment in post, ForeignKey doesn't link comment with that post and there is no value for post_id in table "comment" when comment is created.

Do you please know, what could be wrong? Bellow are two ways how I tried to create db, but none has made connections with ForeingKey.

Tryed using Pragma to force foreignkey, but it didnt help. Tried to enforce ForeignKey on with sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; but it does not persist.

Here is my code:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///userdata.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///userdata.db')

def _fk_pragma_on_connect(dbapi_con, con_record):
    dbapi_con.execute('pragma foreign_keys=ON')

from sqlalchemy import event
event.listen(engine, 'connect', _fk_pragma_on_connect)

class Post(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'post'

    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(String(50))
    subtitle = db.Column(String(50))
    author = db.Column(String(20))
    date_posted = db.Column(DateTime)
    content = db.Column(Text)
    post_rel = relationship('Comment', 
                            back_populates='comment_rel', 
                            foreign_keys='[Comment.post_id]')

    def get_comments(self):
        return     Comments.query.filter_by(
            post_id=post.id).order_by(Comments.timestamp.desc())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)

class Comment(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'comment'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.String(140))
    author = db.Column(db.String(32))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.utcnow, index=True)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id'), nullable=False)
    comment_rel = relationship('Post', uselist=False, back_populates='post_rel')

    def __init__(self, text, author, timestamp):
     """"""
     self.text = text
     self.author = author
     self.timestamp = timestamp

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)

    def show(self):
        return self.author + '\n' + self.text

@app.route('/addcomment', methods=['POST'])
def addcomment():
    commentar = request.form['commentar']
    comment_done = Comment(text=commentar, author=current_user.username,
    timestamp=datetime.now())
    db.session.add(comment_done, 'PRAGMA foreign_keys=on')
    db.session.commit()

    return render_template('post.html', post=post)
```

Comment: What do you mean that the connection is not made? Do you mean that the db engine fails to connect, or perhaps that the db relationship fails to backpopulate?

Comment: DB relationship is problem here and foreign key collumn have always NULL value. I tried every possible example from documentation with children/parent tables, but even those haven't been working as expected.

Comment: Please include an example of how you make a comment in post, or in other words a [mcve].

Comment: there is a `One To One` relation between `Post` and `Comment`. Is this right? I think it must be `One To Many`

Comment: I edited original post with example of comment. ForeignKeys are always off. I tried to turn them on with sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON; on opend db, but it does not persist and after next check, it is OFF again.

Comment: In your example you don't pass a value for `post_id`, or `comment_rel`, when creating the comment. It follows that the foreign key is left NULL. Though you've defined `post_id` as NOT NULL (`nullable=False`), has that always been the case? In other words have you added that after creating the tables? If so, you'll have to migrate the DB schema as well. The second argument to `Session.add()` is `_warn`, which defaults to True and is undocumented. Why are you passing a string?